# How Transpose a multi index datas in a single line using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the series below.

```
df1
   Product
M1 Product1
   Product2
M2 Product1
   Product3
M3 Product1
   Product4
```

There is any resource in pandas that allow transposing data inside a multi-index in a single line? As the sample below.

```
df1

   Product  ProducNew
M1 Product1 Product2
M2 Product1 Product3
M3 Product1 Product4
```

Comment: what is `print (df1.index)` ? Because this seems not MultiIndex

Comment: It's a hier_index.

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Hi Jazz, Thankyou for the help. I So beginner and have no background to provide all details related to a problem a need to solve. But you help me a lot.

Comment: yop, and is is reason why post this comment. Do you check links, especially first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the index and create two columns with first and end values

```
df.groupby(df.index)['Product'].agg(product='first', productNew='last')

     product productNew
M1  Product1   Product2
M2  Product1   Product3
M3  Product1   Product4
```

Comment: @jezrael will be oldest and newest :) OP can make an list and explode it, if he needs

Comment: yop, it is totally unclear, in question is no MultiIndex, no Series, so hard to know what OP need...

Comment: Thank you splach58, i tried this also. But this return the error (
TypeError: aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func_or_funcs')

Comment: what version of pandas do you use?

Comment: Try old style - `df.groupby(df.index)['Product'].agg([('product','first'), ('productNew','last')])`

Comment: i using 0.24.2.

Comment: It worked perfectly for my project. It's possible to adopt this logic for N products?

Comment: Or you can create a new question to get more attention

Comment: Yes, i will. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

This code you suggest is returning the df below.

```
    0
0  Product1
1  Product2
2  Product1
3  Product3
4  Product1
5  Product4...
```

Sorry not be too clear guys, i'm beginner.